# observe localstorage changes in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage

I have a single-page app in which I need to react on every change in localstorage, it looks something like:

```
MyComponent {
    someFuncWhichIsCalledEveryTimeWhenLocalStorageChanges() {
        console.log('local storage changed!');
    }
    
    funcThatChangesLocalStorage() {
        localstorage.setItem('key',val);
        localstorage.getItem('key')
    }
}
```

And I've tried to use localstorage event:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
   ...
});
```

but that didn't work... so I'm thinking about using `Observable<>`, just don't know how to implement it properly.

Comment: try `document.addEventListener`

Comment: @dandavis `window.addEventListener` is the correct implementation. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent).

Comment: @tasha please see if the proposed solutions worked for you and update the answer

Answer (score 48):

**Huge caveat** from the [MDN docs: Window storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event):

> [`window.addEventListener('storage', ...)`] won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made.

So that's probably why it didn't work for you (and for me as well) - you were trying to respond to this listener on other parts of the same page.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a function that makes proxy methods on an object

```
function watchAnyObject(
  object = {},
  methods = [],
  callbackBefore = function () {},
  callbackAfter = function () {},
) {
  for (let method of methods) {
    const original = object[method].bind(object);
    const newMethod = function (...args) {
      callbackBefore(method, ...args);
      const result = original.apply(null, args);
      callbackAfter(method, ...args);
      return result;
    };
    object[method] = newMethod.bind(object);
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
watchAnyObject(
  window.localStorage,
  ['setItem', 'getItem', 'removeItem'],
  (method, key, ...args) =>
    console.log(`call ${method} with key ${key} and args ${args}`),
);
```

you can add your listener *someFuncWhichIsCalledEveryTimeWhenLocalStorageChanges* in the component constructor

```
constructor() {
  watchAnyObject(window.localStorage, ['setItem', 'getItem', 'removeItem'], this.someFuncWhichIsCalledEveryTimeWhenLocalStorageChanges);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The **[localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage)** interface (a handy wrapper for the HTML5 localStorage API) conveniently fires change events *on the same* page/tab/window in which the storage event occurred. Disclaimer: I am the author of the interface.

Once you install **localDataStorage**, this sample code will let you see those change events:

```
function nowICanSeeLocalStorageChangeEvents( e ) {
    console.log(
        "subscriber: "    + e.currentTarget.nodeName + "\n" +
        "timestamp: "     + e.detail.timestamp + " (" + new Date( e.detail.timestamp ) + ")" + "\n" +
        "prefix: "        + e.detail.prefix    + "\n" +
        "message: "       + e.detail.message   + "\n" +
        "method: "        + e.detail.method    + "\n" +
        "key: "           + e.detail.key       + "\n" +
        "old value: "     + e.detail.oldval    + "\n" +
        "new value: "     + e.detail.newval    + "\n" +
        "old data type: " + e.detail.oldtype   + "\n" +
        "new data type: " + e.detail.newtype
    );
};
document.addEventListener(
    "localDataStorage"
    , nowICanSeeLocalStorageChangeEvents
    , false
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Simplified solution !

```js
const localStore = localStorage.setItem;

localStorage.setItem = function(key, value) {
  const event = new Event('localUpdated');
        event.key = key; 
        event.value = value; 
  
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
  localStore.apply(this, arguments);
};

const localStoreHandler = function(e) {
  console.log(` localStorage.set('${e.key}', '${e.value}') updated`);
};

document.addEventListener("localUpdated", localStoreHandler, false);


localStorage.setItem('username', 'amoos');

// After 2 second
setTimeout( ()=>  localStorage.setItem('username', 'rifat'), 2000)
```

Comment: possibly need to set event bubbles=true

Answer (score 0):

The storage event fires when a storage area (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of another document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen the storage change event in the same document, you can add a storage changed event emit function just like below.
When you use localStorage.setItem("xx", "xx"), and trigger this function after it, you will detect the event~

```
export function emitStorageChangedEvent() {
  const iframeEl = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframeEl.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);

  iframeEl.contentWindow?.localStorage.setItem("t", Date.now().toString());
  iframeEl.remove();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`window.addEventListener('storage', ...)` [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Make sure you are using the correct [event properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent).

[Here is a basic example of the event listener.](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/web-storage/event.js)

Comment: this is not what the OP is asking for. as it was already pointed out an event listener for "storage" does NOT work on the same page, the changes are done. please read the note in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event